# How to get number of objects with common properties from context using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I would like to get the amount/number of objects within a given time based on the objects properties `Group` and `Id` from my context using `LINQ`. 
So the result should give me a list (descending or ascending) that lists the objects(Alarms) based on the occurrence so that I can see how often an alarm has occurred within a time frame. What I have so far is only the following:

```
List<Alarm> alarmList = ctx.Alarm.Where(t => t.TimeStamp >= span)
                           .Where(s => s.Active)
                           .GroupBy(g => g.Group)
                           .OrderByDescending(c => c.Count())
                           .SelectMany(a => a).ToList();
```

It gives me all the alarms within the defined time frame ordered by group.
I couldn't figure out how to involve also the property Id
and count the objects with the same group + id.

Is there a way to get this done?

Comment: Bit confusing, can you show the sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to group by combination of `Group` and `Id` and not just by `Group` and then ordering it descendingly:

```
List<Alarm> alarmList = ctx.Alarm.Where(t => t.TimeStamp >= span)
                           .Where(s => s.Active)
                           .GroupBy(g => g.Group.ToString() + "_" + g.Id.ToString())
                           .OrderByDescending(c => c.Count())
                           .SelectMany(a => a).ToList();
```

Or, if you don't want to use `string` as the group key (normally I would), you could create an anonymous type:

```
List<Alarm> alarmList = ctx.Alarm.Where(t => t.TimeStamp >= span)
                           .Where(s => s.Active)
                           .GroupBy(g => new { g.Group, g.Id })
                           .OrderByDescending(c => c.Count())
                           .SelectMany(a => a).ToList();
```

If you want to count the number of alarms per `Group + Id`, then you should leave your solution in `IGrouping` format for a while:

```
var alarmGroup = ctx.Alarm.Where(t => t.TimeStamp >= span)
                   .Where(s => s.Active)
                   .GroupBy(g => new { g.Group, g.Id })
                   .OrderByDescending(c => c.Count());
```

And as you need you item, you could simply show the number of item per group like:

```
foreach (var grp in alarmGroup)
    Console.WriteLine(grp.Count() + " " + grp.Key.Group + "+" + grp.Key.Id);
```

Comment: Yes that's the first step, but it does not solve my problem completely. Now I have "sorted" the list, so all objects with the same properties are listed. But what I ultimately want is to know how many of these combinations (g.Group.ToString() + "_" + g.Id.ToString()), per combination, I have. Like 1 x (Group1+ID1), 15 x (Group15+ID8)...

Comment: @ck84vi you have already done it with `c.Count` actually.... c.Count will have the number of items per group.

Comment: if you want to get the item based on the number of the items too, then, you should not use `SelectMany` too fast.. That is, leave your item after `OrderByDescending`, then you really have groups of alarms based on their count, not the complete list of alarm - not yet.

Comment: Thx a lot. That is exactly what I was trying to get!!

Comment: @ck84vi yep, don't use `SelectMany` too early... ;)